# Oracle not accepting decimal numbers but instead coming up as null

Tags: oracle

Using Oracle Express 11g and SQL developer, when I do any script or calculation, Oracle will not accept any number with a decimal point, returning null instead. As an example:

- If I do 2 divided by 3, the answer comes up as null, instead of .66
- 10 divided by 4 comes up as null instead of 2.5

Steps taken so far: I have set the tables and columns to various datatypes, defined the scale and precision, and verified the language/region settings.

Here is my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE DCP_SITE_MAP 
(
  LOCXREF VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
, XVALUE NUMBER(10, 2)
, YVALUE NUMBER(10, 2)
)
```

The values that I attempted to add to the DCP_SITE_MAP table:

- XVALUE = 13 : YVALUE = 5
- XVALUE = 13.25 : YVALUE = 5

As a note, after I entered 13.25 and committed the entry, the 13.25 was changed to 13.

Then I ran SQL like this:

```
SELECT XVALUE as Expr1,
       XVALUE *.25 as Expr2,
       XVALUE/YVALUE as EXPR3
FROM DCP_SITE_MAP
```

I would get a null value back from Expr2 and EXPR3. In addition, the following queries would also return null:

```
Select XVALUE/60 as EXPR2 from  DCP_SITE_MAP

SELECT count(*)/60 from DCP_SITE_MAP
```

Comment: What's your database schema, and what statement are you using to insert the row into the database?

Comment: If I take a new table and put some whole numbers in it, then a do anything to it that would make it come out as a decimal,(like divide by three) it will return as null.  If I manually enter it in, it then reverts to null.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual statements and outputs you are getting, as well as the table definition. Can you see the 'whole numbers' if you just query them and don't try to modify them? Also say what client you are using to insert and query.

Comment: a fellow emp gave me the above so that you didn't have to wait as long.

Comment: In the future, it's way better received when you include all the information for the question off the bat. That said, when you run `DESCRIBE DCP_SITE_MAP`, does the table structure match that of the CREATE TABLE statement? Also, try CASTing the expression to a decimal; does that make things any better? `SELECT CAST((XVALUE * 0.25) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Expr2 FROM DCP_SITE_MAP`

Comment: It matches the table.  Also, I get the same result with CAST.  Entering in the value as a decimal does not correct the problem either.

Comment: Are you only seeing this behaviour in SQL Developer, or can you reproduce in SQL\*Plus too? Is it happening in a worksheet or in a grid or both? What about if you open the table from the object browser and look at the data tab? Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, the Decimal data type is written as
`decimal(p,s)`

Precision can range from 1 to 38.

Where p is the precision and s is the scale.

For example, decimal(3,1) is a number that has 2 digits before the decimal and 1 digit after the decimal.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with what is being described? The question also refers to setting scale and precision already.